# Cannot read property length of undefined in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to show some data on a Datatable. The data is called from an Ajax request and the response is a Json array, it looks like this:

```
[{"item": "one", "price": 22, "status": "free"}, {"item": "two", "price": 15, "status": "taken"}]
```

And here is my request:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('mytable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": "myurl",
      "dataType": 'json',
      "dataSrc": '',

      "columns": [
        {"data": "item" },
        {"data": "price" },
        {"data": "status"},  
    ]

  } );
} );
</script>
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<table id="mytable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ITEM</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The issue is that the data is not being shown on the table.
I think the problem happens when Datatables tries to handle my JSON data, since i'm getting this error on my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Is the issue that your table is not displaying data?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, i edited my post right now

Comment: Your tables id is 'open' and your JS is trying to find `$('mytable')`

Comment: Just an error when creating the question, corrected it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTables: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287402/datatables-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you don't need to make the table in HTML. Datatables creates the table.

Second thing is that you are not properly calling your table `$('#mytable')`

Third it doesn't seem like you are passing any data to the table:

Create a variable with your data:
`var data = [{"item": "one", "price": 22, "status": "free"}, {"item": "two", "price": 15, "status": "taken"}]`

Add it to the table:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable( {
      "data": data,
      "columns": [
        {"data": "item" },
        {"data": "price" },
        {"data": "status"},  
    ]

  } );
} );
```

link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/edpbk0gc/3/

**EDIT**

Since you are doing an `ajax` call you will need to specify `"ajax"` instead of `"data"`

```
$('#mytable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: "/fetch_data",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "item" },
        {"data": "price" },
        {"data": "status"},  
    ]

  } );
} );
```

You basically just do your ajax call in there however you'd like.

Reference this [doc](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html).

Comment: You can reference this example if your data source is in JS: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: @Dementic fixed link, also didn't notice you could add resources on fiddle like that, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Wait, my data source is not a variable. I'm retrieving the data to use on the table from an URL, so how can i use it in a variable?

Comment: Are you fetching it via an ajax call? you can pass the data from wherever its coming from and assign it to a variable and pass it to a method that creates your table. If you are using AJAX it will be a little different

Comment: Yes, i'm fetching it via an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table selector with `$('#mytable')` as @ricks mentioned and you need to match your json from the ajax to the format expected by datatables, something like this:

```
{ 
    data: [{"item": "one", "price": 22, "status": "free"}, {"item": "two", "price": 15, "status": "taken"}] 
}
```

Comment: `you need to match your json from the ajax to the format expected by datatables` not correct, it can be custom https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41385/custom-json-format

Comment: I know but I supposed it's pretty simple to fix the format instead of using the `ajax.dataSrc` option, otherwise no one would have to ask for help in implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since the question was asked, but nevertheless, I think I know how to solve it.

The `dataSrc` property is in the wrong spot.

The "ajax" node in the `datatable` setup needs to be broken down into an object. Inside the object, you need to specify the `dataSrc` property and set it to empty string.

so, the new code should look like:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('mytable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {      
        "url":"myurl",
        "type":"GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
      },
      "columns": [
        {"data": "item" },
        {"data": "price" },
        {"data": "status"},  
      ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Observe how the

```js
"ajax": "myurl"
```

is changed to

```js
"ajax": {
  "url": "myurl",
  "type": "GET",
  "dataSrc": ""
}
```